What repair methods will work for a fabric-coverered hose?
I have a fabric-encased hose that works really well except I must have dragged it over a nail head or something like that and now it leaks, a lot.  The leaking area doesn't have an obvious hole or rip in it that I can see, plus I don't even know what to call this type of hose in order to research it without the help of this community.  Is there a repair kit or method to make this usable again?  Thank you


There are hose repair kits, but you need to know where the leak is.  If the fabric is just a covering, the inner lining/real hose is leaking somewhere.

the fabric is only a cover ... it's the tube inside that cracked.

Cut the hose before and after the breaks. Attach ends with hose mender as shown in picture: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-5-8-in-Metal-Hose-Repair-Mender-with-Stainless-Steel-Clamp-Hose-and-Sprinkler-Repair-27990/204735795 . You'll need to get size to match hose.
